# Play2! Action.async vs Action. Is it only about ExecutionContext?

Tags: asynchronous, playframework

recenlty I am wondering about some simple concepts of Play Framework. What is the difference between Action and Action.async if both of them run async. I've found pretty good explanation - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework-dev/30MqnKDp0Fs/25PU-Y0RhGoJ , which leads me to final question - if Action by itself is async, is it only about ExecutionContext?

So you write Action.async if you for instance make face recognition computation in some particular action and you would like to separate displaying Homepage from this intensive CPU algorithm execution in terms of thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

With a plain `Action` Play will take care of wrapping your code into an asynchronous construct (`Future`). When you already have a `Future` result you can use the `Action.async` construct. By default, you may use the default `ExecutionContext` (roughly equivalent to a `ThreadPool`) by importing `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._` - but you may also want to set-up custom contexts, such as e.g.

```
object Contexts {
  implicit val expensiveDbLookups: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.expensive-db-lookups")
}
```

And in `conf/application.conf`

```
contexts {

    expensive-db-lookups {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-max = 4
        }
    }

}
```

`Action.async` essentially allows you to use `Future`-s directly, a frequent combination being  the [WS library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS):

```
def users = Action.async { implicit request =>
  WS.url("http://www.cloudusers.com/123/list").get().map { response =>
    Ok(response.json)
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you don't have any custom execution contexts it's perfectly ok to only use Action without async?

Comment: Yes. If your action computation depends upon a `Future`, you'd use `Action.async` directly, instead of blocking explicitly in the body of a plain `Action` (as it does not expect a Future, but a concrete value). This is e.g. often the case when you use the asynchronous `WS` library for web service calls.